# Convergence of Secant method or IQI

Tags: convergence-divergence, matlab

We have drawn a graph that shows that the methods do converge but is it possible to obtain values for the rate of convergence of the secant and inverse quadratic interpolation methods for a particular function on MATLAB?

Thank you!

Comment: You would be amazed to know that the secant method has the rate of convergence $1.618\ldots$. Does that look familiar? Why yes,of course it is $$\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$$

Comment: Yes so the rate of convergence output for the secant method should be the same regardless of the function used?

Comment: We just arent 100% sure how to calculate this rate on MATLAB? :/

Comment: [See wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method)

Comment: Unfortunately we couldnt find anything relevant there but thanks for the help!

Comment: @Amzoti Yes Ill try that now thank you!!

Comment: @Amzoti well we used the secant method to obtain the root of the function x.^3 -2 and the root output was 1.2599? Do you need all of the iterates? Thanks for your help by the way much appreciated

Comment: @Amzoti we were looking at that website earlier but we thought that we were looking to obtain the value 1.618 (which the equation already has in it) and therefore we couldnt use it? But maybe we are wrong?

Comment: we were trying to give the ratio method a try but we dont obtain answers that resemble the figure of 1.618 :/

Comment: That would be great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It can be proven that the rate of convergence of the secant method is superlinear (meaning, better than linear but less than quadratic).

**Theorem**

**Convergence of the Secant method**. Suppose that $f$ and its first two derivatives are continuous in an interval $I$ that contains a zero $c$ of $f$ , and suppose that there exists a positive constant $\gamma$ such that $|f'(x)| \gt \gamma \gt 0$ for all $x$ in $I$. Then there exists a constant $M$ such that for all starting values $x_0$ and $x_1$ sufficiently close to $c$, the sequence produced by the Secant Method will converge to $c$ and the error $e_n = c- x_n$ will satisfy

$$|e_n| \lt M~|e_{n-1}|^r, n = 2, 3, \ldots,$$

where

$$r = \dfrac{1}{2} ( 1 + \sqrt{5}) \approx 1.618033988749894848204587.$$

**Observation** When the Secant method converges to a zero $c$ with $f'(c) \ne 0$, the number of correct digits increases by about $62 \%$ per iteration.

**Example**

$$f(x) = x^2 - 2, (x_0, x_1) = (1.5, 2.0)$$

The exact root of this is (lets use $25-$digits of accuracy):

$$c = \sqrt{2} \approx 1.414213562373095048801688$$

Using Taylor's Theorem, we can find $M$ as:

$M = \left|\dfrac{f''(c)}{2f'(c)}\right|^{r-1} = \left|\dfrac{f''(\sqrt{2})}{2f'(\sqrt{2})} \right|^{0.618033} = \left|\dfrac{2}{2\sqrt{2}} \right|^{0.618033} = 0.525932303452186758952445$

Using the Secant Method, we generate the following iterates:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
n & x_n & x_{n+1}-x_{n} & e_n = c - x_n \\
\hline
1 & 1.500000000000000000000000 & 0.500000000000000000000000 &  -   \\
2 & 2.000000000000000000000000 & 0.571428571428571428571429 &  -   \\
3 & 1.428571428571428571428571 & 0.011904761904761904761905 &  1.435786619833352262688 \times 10^{-2}    \\
4 & 1.416666666666666666666667 & 0.002440725244072524407252 &  2.45310429357161786498 \times 10^{-3}  \\
5 & 1.414225941422594142259414 & 0.000012368322458657593815 &  1.237904949909345773 \times 10^{-5}  \\
6 & 1.414213573100135484665599 & 1.0726993487515235 \times 10^{-8} &  1.072704043586391 \times 10^{-8}  \\
7 & 1.414213562373141997150364 & 4.6948348497 \times 10^{-14} &  4.694834868  \times 10^{-14}  \\
8 & 1.414213562373095048801867 & 1.78 \times 10^{-22} &  1.8  \times 10^{-22} &  
\end{array}
$$

Now, using the above data (or the data in your problem), just compare and verify:

$$|~e_{n+1}~| \approx |e_n|^{1.618} \left| \dfrac{f''(c)}{2f'(c)}\right|^{0.618}$$

All of this tells you that the convergence rate for the Secant Method is:

$$r = \dfrac{1}{2} ( 1 + \sqrt{5}) \approx 1.618033988749894848204587.$$